# Multiple React components in a single module

Tags: reactjs, gulp, browserify

I am new to the whole browserify thing.
I have been trying to use browserify + reactify + gulp to transform, minify and combine a React application.
As long as I have a single `React.createClass` with a single `module.exports = MyComponent` everything works fine.
Since I have several shared components I physically host in the same file and reuse across projects, I would like to export more than one component.
I have tried an array:

`module.exports = [Component1, Component2]`

and have also tried an object with multiple properties:

`module.exports = {Comp1: Componenet1, Comp2: Component2}` and have also tried in-lining the calls to `createClass` in the object, but that didn't help.

Is there a way to do this or do I have to split every component in to a seperate JSX file?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I have put multiple components in one file and export the object like you suggested.

```
module.exports = {
    comp1: Component1,
    comp2: Component2
}
```

Then where they are used do

```
var comp1 = require('your/path/to/components').comp1;
var comp2 = require('your/path/to/components').comp2;
```

Comment: This is a bad idea in case you only want comp1. In this case you're requiring the entire model when calling  that first require and you're sending code to the browser that it doesn't need.

Comment: This will not work with webpack2, since they changed module.exports to read-only, if any 'import' statement is used (es6 style)

Answer (score 35):

You can do like this, with an **index.js** file into your `/components/` folder

### /components/index.js

```
import Users from './Users/Users';
import User from './Users/User';


module.exports = {
  User,
  Users
}
```

### IMPORT

```
import { Users, User } from './components';
```

As you can see, I named my file **index.js**, it prevent me from write it in the import declaration. If you want to name your file with another name than **index.js**, you'd have to write the name of the file in the import, Node won't guess it ! ^^

Comment: This gave me an error, but using the following worked:

export { User, users}

Answer (score 2):

Define functions

```
function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b
}
function sub(a, b) {
  return a - b
}
function mul(a, b) {
  return a * b
}
```

Define export
`export { sum, sub, mul }`

Import functions you need
`import { sum, sub } from 'myfile'`
or all the functions
`import * as myfunctions from 'myfile'`

and call as
`sum(1+1)` or `myfunctions.sum(1+1)`

src: https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-export-multiple-functions-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to react and I faced this situation too. And this is how I overcame it.

Along to this question it also answers the following error:

*export 'default' (imported as 'db') was not found in './index.js' (possible exports: auth, db).*

*1st method* - use export default & don’t destructure while importing

**index.js**

```
const db = // module 1;
const auth = // module 2;

export default { db, auth}; // notice the default keyword here
```

**while importing in other file**

```
import db from "./index.js"
```

*2nd method* - use export & destructure while importing

**index.js**

```
const db = // module 1;
const auth = // module 2;

export { db, auth};
```

**and while importing**

```
import { db } from "./index.js"
```

***Please note when to use destructuring while using the import statement***

Answer (score 0):

I use function to return component.

```
 module.exports = {
   comp1: function(){
     return Component1;
   }
 }
```

Then

```
var myCompontents = require('./components');
var comp1 = myComponents.comp1();
```

Comment: I don't follow how adding another layer of indirection in the form of a function wrapper achieves anything. `module.exports = {Component1}` is much simpler for both importer and exporter.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me.

In a single file, `MultipleComponents.js`, add two or more components like below.

```
const ComponentA = () => <div>Component A works! </div>

const ComponentB = () => <div>Component B works! </div>


export {ComponentA, ComponentB} // Export this way without using default
```

Now import these components in any other component you wish like below

```
import {ComponentA} from 'your/directory/MutlipleFiles;
```

Answer (score -3):

You can simply export multiple components as an array:

```
module.exports = [Component1, Component2]
```

Then to use the components:

```
var MyComponents = require('your/path/to/components');
var Component1 = MyComponents[0];
var Component2 = MyComponents[1];
```

Comment: this is a bad practice. why would you output an array and not an object? this is better in every possible way:
`var Component1  = MyComponents.Component1;`
`var Component2  = MyComponents.Component2;`

Comment: @VitalikZaidman For the reason that Op states "and have also tried an object with multiple properties", yes an object would be better practice and if you wanted to be optimal I would suggest using ES6 import and destructuring.