# React: storing components in an object

Tags: reactjs

I have a few dozen fields in my users' profiles, and I'm trying to build an efficient means of displaying them in the appropriate input form components.

eg, a profile might look like:

```
profile1={
  name: 'Cornelius Talmadge',
  phone: '1'
}
```

And if I could stack components in something like this...

```
export const FieldCatalogue = {
  name: <TextField defaultValue={this.state.userProfile.name} label={"Name"} />
}
```

...then I could do something like this:

```
for (let field in Object.keys(profile1)) {
  return FieldCatalogue[field]
}
```

which would be super cool.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30762734/multiple-react-components-in-a-single-module) has a great answer for if my input components were all constructed via the normal syntax (eg, `Component = React.createClass({..})`), but:

a. that's a lot of boilerplate

b. i'd have to pass props galore to each one, which isn't optimal

The perfect situation for me would basically be passing input components almost as strings, such that they fell into the scope (state, props, etc.) of whatever parent component they were rendered.

Is this possible and/or advisable?

Answer (score 2):

> The perfect situation for me would basically be passing input
>   components almost as strings, such that they fell into the scope
>   (state, props, etc.) of whatever parent component they were rendered.
>
> Is this possible and/or advisable?

Yes, it is actually possible! No, I don't think this is something I would actually use. But it works, and it looks kinda cool. In my example, the FieldCatalogue components obviously don't have their own separate `this.state` object, but by binding them to the parent component `this` they automagically inherit the correct context.

Note that the example will not work if the components are defined as arrow functions, because arrow functions never have own `this` objects.

Oh, and the key in `<Tmp key={i} />` is just there because we need to supply React with some kind of identifier when we loop over an array.

I had to try this as an exercise, and this is quite neat:

https://jsfiddle.net/dannyjolie/e9s09xrm/

```
const FieldCatalogue = {
  name: function() {
    return <input defaultValue = {this.state.userProfile.name} label = {"Name"}/>;
  },
  age: function() {
    return <input defaultValue = {this.state.userProfile.age}/>;
  }
}
const App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      userProfile: {
        name: 'Name in parent state',
        age: 'Age in parent state'
      }
    };
  },
  render: function() {
    let content = Object.keys(FieldCatalogue).map((objkey, i) => {
      let Tmp = FieldCatalogue[objkey].bind(this)
      return <Tmp key = {i} />;
    });
    return <div>{content}</div>);
  }
});
```

This way the `this`context of the parent component is passed to the FieldCatalogue components, and it just works. Really not sure if it's a good thing to do though.

Answer (score 0):

You could map over the user objects keys and match them to corresponding components in `fieldCatalogue`. If the key exists, render the component at that key and pass all of the parent components props in:

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/FullR/pen/GZrGyP?editors=1010)

```
const fieldCatalogue = { // stateless component functions rather than React element literals
  name(props) {
    return <div>Name: {props.value}</div>
  },

  age(props) {
    return <div>Age: {props.value}</div>
  }
};

class ProfileFields extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {userProfile} = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        {Object.keys(userProfile).map((key) => {
          if(fieldCatalogue.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            const FieldComponent = fieldCatalogue[key];
            return (<FieldComponent {...this.props} value={userProfile[key]}/>);
          } else {
            return null;
          }
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Alternatively, your field components could just handle undefined values by returning `null`. Then you could render all of them and only the ones that exist on the user object would be rendered.