# How to store React component in object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have an object of all apps:

```
 export const allApps: appInterface[] = [
  {
    id: uuidv4(),
    name: "Minesweeper",
    icon: minesweeperIcon,
    disabled: false,
  },
];
```

I want to add component property to each object like this:

```
 export const allApps: appInterface[] = [
  {
    id: uuidv4(),
    name: "Minesweeper",
    icon: minesweeperIcon,
    disabled: false,
    component: Minesweeper, //It is imported as import Minesweeper from ../Components/Minesweeper";
  },
];
```

And then I want to display all components in App.js:

```
allApps.forEach((app)=>{
  <div>{app.component}<div> // for eg: <div><Minesweeper/></div>
});
```

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: Indeed. Components are just functions. You can assign them however you like. Writing JSX is just another syntax for invoking these functions and concatenating their output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React / JSX Dynamic Component Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29875869/react-jsx-dynamic-component-name)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React: storing components in an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36073258/react-storing-components-in-an-object)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try as below code it should work.

```
allApps.map((app)=>{
const { component: Component } = app;
  return <Component />;
});
```

Comment: For those wanting more details, it seems like you should never call a component function directly and instead use JSX/TSX semantics as shown in this answer. In my case it led to a pretty tricky bug, where it worked for some components and not for others. I struggled so much to find the right semantics for going from function to component in this case, thanks a lot for this elegant solution !

Comment: just name your  file with the .tsx or jsx extension and it should work