# React - How to Export Multiple Components on same File, preventing <Unknown/> Component on Dev Tools

Tags: reactjs

okay so if I have one react component I can:

```
const Home = () => (....)
export default Home;
```

Now I have a file called `About.js` where I am exporting multiple components as they're related.

```
export const Staff = () => (...)

export const Employee = () => (...)
```

in my App.js

```
import { Staff, Employee } from "./components/About";
```

All works, however, react dev-tools says the components above are `<Unknown/>`

[image]

What is best practice to export multiples components from a file avoiding the `<Unknown/>` output?

**Solution**
Thanks to @Khun on comments bellow

```
About.js

const Staff = () => (...)
const Employee = () => (...)

export {Staff, Employee}

in my App.js

    import { Staff, Employee } from "./components/About";
```

That removed the `<Unknown/>` from react dev tools.

Ps: I understand the discrepancy on best practice, however, this did resolve my question above.

Comment: To be honest with you, the best practice would be to only implement one component per file.

Comment: I was wondering if there were a way to combine both

Comment: Still you need to export multiple components from same file, this would help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46039976/exporting-multiple-modules-in-react-js

Comment: @Jayavel thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

First, create each components in a different file: Staff.js and Employee.js. Export them like this: `export { Staff };` and `export { Employee };`

Now create another file to handle multiple exports. Let's call it About.js and here is the content:

```
export * from './Staff';
export * from './Employee';
```

Now just use it as you did:

```
import { Staff, Employee } from "./components/About";
```

Comment: So diff files for each component, only way to go?

Comment: If you want your code to scale and be maintainable, that's your best bet.

Comment: @NullisTrue of course you can still use it in the same file but not recommended! Simply create all classes and export them at the bottom. export { Staff, Employee ];

Comment: Copy that. Thanks guys!