# How to use multiple `export default ` in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, export

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';


function BlogTrends(props) {
  BlogTrends.propTypes = {
    data: PropTypes.array
  };
  return (
    <div className="container blog-trends">
       <h3>{props.data[0].head}</h3>
       <h5 className="mar-t-25" >{props.data[0].desc}</h5>
    </div>
  );
}
function BlogDescription() {
  return (
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-md-12">
        <h5>Kitchen </h5>
        <p>Ocean</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default { BlogTrends, BlogDescription };
```

***Error Image:***
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fStld.png

 Tried: 
By removing BlogDescription and making the export statement to 'export default { BlogTrends;' is working . But while I am adding multiple component its not working. tried few things i.e 
`export default { BlogTrends, BlogDescription };` and 
`export { BlogTrends, BlogDescription };`  and

```
export BlogTrends;<br />
export  BlogDescription;<br />
```

Comment: export default can only apply to one thing, so for example export default function BlogDescription() - you can then use export function BlogTrends()

Comment: @rrd yes it worked .. Thanks :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [exporting multiple modules in react.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46039976/exporting-multiple-modules-in-react-js)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have multiple default exports, but you can have multiple (non-default) exports.

Try adding `export` before the function keywords, like `export function BlogDescription() {`

Then to import them you would do `import { BlogDescription } from './myFile'`

Comment: with 'export function BlogTrends(props){}' and `export default { BlogTrends, BlogDescription };` bellow error is coming :<br />
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
<br /> and without `export default { BlogTrends, BlogDescription };` bellow error is coming :<br />
_Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might hav......_

Comment: Where did you change it?

Answer (score 2):

Exporting multiple functions

```
export default myMainFunc;
export { mySecondFunc };
```

Answer (score 1):

The hole point of an export default is that when another file imports from this file without specifying a name it will fall back to the default, if there were several defaults on the file it would defeat this purpose, what you want, is to export each function and you can then have **one** of those as the default for the module, so in your case:

---

**export** function BlogTrends(props) {

**export** function BlogDescription() {

...

**export default** BlogTrends

---

Then on your importing file you can do:

import { BlogTrends } from 'pathToFile' ---> imports BlogTrends function.

import { BlogDescription } from 'pathToFile' ---> imports BlogDescription function.

import **Default** from 'pathToFile' ---> imports BlogTrends function.

---

Reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export