# How can I have multiple default exports in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling

I am getting `A module cannot have multiple default exports`  when i setup my `constants/varConstants.js`  file.

```
export default VARIABLE1 = 'VARIABLE1'
export default VARIABLE2 = 'VARIABLE2'
export default VARIABLE3 = 'VARIABLE3'
export default VARIABLE4 = 'VARIABLE4'
```

my `reducers/reducer.js` file should call on those constants as  `import {VARIABLE1,VARIABLE2,VARIABLE3,VARIABLE4 from /constants/varConstants` for my reducer function.

how can i fix the errors above? Errors are squiggly lines under `export default var...`

Comment: Looks like duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54810022/how-to-use-multiple-export-default-in-react

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use multiple \`export default \` in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54810022/how-to-use-multiple-export-default-in-react)

Answer (score 2):

When you import like this :

```
import {VARIABLE1,VARIABLE2,VARIABLE3,VARIABLE4 from /constants/varConstants
```

it is not default export. This is named export only.
There can only be on default export from a module. Hence the name default.

Export like this to have multiple named exports.

```
const VARIABLE1 = 'VARIABLE1'
const VARIABLE2 = 'VARIABLE2'
const VARIABLE3 = 'VARIABLE3'
const VARIABLE4 = 'VARIABLE4'
export { VARIABLE1,VARIABLE2,VARIABLE3,VARIABLE4 };
```

Then you can use the import statement you are expecting.

Alternatively, you could have done:

```
export const VARIABLE1 = 'VARIABLE1'
export const VARIABLE2 = 'VARIABLE2'
export const VARIABLE3 = 'VARIABLE3'
export const VARIABLE4 = 'VARIABLE4'
```

But i prefer the former. That way I can quickly see what all I am exporting (in case I am not exporting all the variables).

Here is a [doc](https://betterprogramming.pub/understanding-the-difference-between-named-and-default-exports-in-react-2d253ca9fc22)