# How can I display more than one component from the same file in the App.js?

Tags: html, reactjs

I am learning React.js. I need to know how can I display more than one component in App.js. I have 2 pages which are `Home.js and About.js`.

After run the code, just click on About us then you will get only About Page text. But I have About Team and About content too in the About.js file. That is not displaying. I import the

```
import { About, AboutTeam, AboutContent } from "./Pages/About";
```

but never use till now because I don't know where should I add `AboutTeam, AboutContent`. Please check my `App.js` file. I just need when the user clicks on About us then it will display all the components which I have in `About.js`.

I added example here https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-almeida-t6q7w?file=/src/App.js

I am getting

[image]

This is my expected output

[image]

One more doubt; I am using the below code so is this code is the correct way to use?

**Home.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './css/Style.css';

const Home=()=>{
  return(
    <div className="">
        <h2>Home page</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Home;
```

**About.js**

```
    import React from 'react';
    import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
    import './css/Style.css';
    
    const About=()=>{
      return(
        <div className="">
            <h2>About page</h2>
        </div>
      );
    }
const AboutTeam = () => {
  return (
    <div className="">
      <h2>About Team dummy text</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

const AboutContent = () => {
  return (
    <div className="">
      <h2>About content dummy text</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export { About, AboutTeam, AboutContent };
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './css/Style.css';
import HeaderMenu from './components/Header';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import { About, AboutTeam, AboutContent } from "./Pages/About";
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';


const App=()=>{
  return(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <HeaderMenu />
    <div className="">
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
        <Route path="/about"  component={About} />
        </Switch>
    </div>
    <Footer />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
export default App;
```

**Index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [exporting multiple modules in react.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46039976/exporting-multiple-modules-in-react-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write in App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './css/Style.css';
import HeaderMenu from './components/Header';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import { About, AboutTeam, AboutContent } from "./Pages/About";
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

const AboutPage = () => (
  <>
    <About />
    <AboutTeam />
    <AboutContent />
  </>
);

const App=()=>{
  return(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <HeaderMenu />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
        <Route path="/about" component={AboutPage} />
        </Switch>
      <Footer />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: So every time, if I create component then I have to declare like this import { About, AboutTeam, somemore1,somemore2 } from './About.js'?

Comment: I am really appreciate your support here. but I am not getting. Please check my App code in the question.

Comment: if you want to use AboutTeam Component you need to use it because in your Code AboutTeam Component is not used anywhere; you only imported it

Comment: Can you check my code codesandbox.io/s/happy-almeida-t6q7w?file=/src/Pages/About.js

Comment: your Footer.js file is empty

Comment: Yes, I know my footer is empty now I added some code, but that is not my issue, I update my full code in the above link. My issue is I am not able to use them more than one component of the About.js. Please check my About.js file I have 3 component but it is displaying only one.

Comment: Just click on About us then you will get only About Page. But I have About Team and About content too in the About.js file. IN the App.js file I import all 3

Comment: Because you don't use About Team Component. You only imported it but you don't use it; I wrote it above

Comment: Yes, So where should I use that. That is my issue

Comment: It depends on where you want to use those compoents

Comment: I just need when user clicks on About us then all should be display. I am learning the React. Please guide me.

Comment: then you do not need to export AboutTeam Component

const AboutTeam=()=>{
  return(
    <div className="">
      <h2>About Team</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
const About=()=>{
  return(
    <>
      <div className="">
        <h2>About page</h2>
      </div>
      <AboutTeam />
    </>
  );
}

Comment: But why? I have 3 section my about page each section I have to display.

Comment: I checked your code but that is not a good way to use it.  I updated my code in the question. Please check it once.

Comment: Yes, This time it's working. I am really appreciate your answer and support.  Thanks for the help. Upvote from my aide.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `import {About, AboutTeam} from ...`, then you need to export 2 variables:

```
export const About = ...
export const AboutTeam = ...
```

It's not advisable to have too many components in 1 file, but if you really want to [import all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Description), that is also possible:

```
import * as About from './About.js'

... <About.About /> ... <About.AboutTeam /> ...
```

Comment: So every time, if I create component then I have to declare like this import { About, AboutTeam, somemore1,somemore2 } from './About.js'?

Comment: you don't *have* to, you can use `import *` as per my updated answer... but the explicit imports are more popular.

Comment: " It's not advisable to have too many components in 1 file,"   Why I am asking this because I have 6-7 sections in my about page and each layout is different.

Comment: anything you don't like about `import {...1-7...} from './About'`? you can use newlines inside the statement to make it more readable...

Comment: I added my code in About.js and export like  export {About, AboutTeam, AboutContent} then I added import {About, AboutTeam,AboutContent} from './pages/About'; Now I am still getting only   About content. I am not getting the AboutTeam,AboutContent

Comment: if you have a different question from what you asked in your question, feel free to ask a new question. I won't be able to help you without a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Wait a min I am sharing my code link for better understant

Comment: I added my code here : https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-almeida-t6q7w?file=/src/Pages/About.js

Comment: you never use the imported `AboutTeam` and `AboutContent` - I have no idea what you expect to happen :(

Comment: I used in the App.js  import { About, AboutTeam, AboutContent } from "./Pages/About";

Comment: yes, you imported them. but what do you want to *do* with them? unused import is similar to unused variable, if you write `let x = 2` and then never *use* `x` anywhere else, it's equally useless as importing variables without actually using them - and equally mysterious to the readers of the code about your reasons *why* you wanted to import it

Comment: Yes, now I need to know where I have to use that.......Let me explain again. In the about page I have 3 component and all are exported. Then I import in the App.js Now I need to now how can I access that. Please check my App.js code

Answer (score 0):

```
// About.js

const AboutTeam = () => {
  return (
    <div className="">
      <h2>About Team</h2>
    </div>
  );
};
const About = () => {
  return (
    <div className="">
      <h2>About page</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export { About, AboutTeam };
```

Then import it as

```
import { About, AboutTeam } from './About.js'
```

Comment: So every time, if i create component then I have to declare in the import?

Comment: you will have to export it once like `export { About, AboutTeam }` and while importing any of `About` or `AboutTeam` , it can be imported as named import.. like: `import { About } from "./About.js`

Comment: So every time, if I create component then I have to declare like this import { About, AboutTeam, somemore1,somemore2 } from './About.js'?

Comment: yes, if you are using all the components ` About, AboutTeam, somemore1,somemore2` in the file you are importing into... then import eveything

Comment: I added my code here: Please check it https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-almeida-t6q7w?file=/src/Pages/About.js

Comment: can help me in this? Please

Comment: Just click on About us then you will get only About Page. But I have About Team and About content too in the About.js file.  I haven't use  About Team Component. I just import.

Answer (score 0):

you can create more than one component in one file like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './css/Style.css';

export const AboutTeam =() => {
    return (
     <div>About Team Page </div>
    )
}

export const About =()=>{
  return(
    <div className="">
        <h2>About page</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

all things are looking fine, but you should not leave `className` empty and inside `BrowserRouter` there should be only one wrapper so you should wrap all elements inside a `div`.

Answer (score 0):

use **export** instead of **export default** to export both the component from the same file (About.js)

```
//About.js

import React from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './css/Style.css';

const About=()=>{
  return(
    <div className="">
        <h2>About page</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

const AboutTeam=()=>{
  return(
    <div className="">
      <h2>About Team</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

export {About, AboutTeam};
```

and then import it in the file you need,

```
import {About, AboutTeam} from "./About.js";
```

Apart from the solution, one more thing to keep in mind is

- component exported using **export default**, is imported like

  **import About from "./path of file";**
- component exported using **export**, is/are imported like

  **import {About, AboutTeam} from "./path of file";**