# Export multiple react objects from other dirs

Tags: reactjs

I'm very new to React so please excuse my ignorance. I basically want to know the "way" to export multiple ReactJS objects from directories for larger codebases and best practices. This is not really in the [ReactJS tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html).

Let's say I have a file `./main.js` and I want to import a lib (from a dir because I might have other ones).

Let's say I have a library in a dir `./library_dir/my_lib.js` and I want to use it in `./main.js` like so.

In `./main.js`, I might want to use this lib and initialize some `ExampleComponent` like this:

```
var my_lib = require('./library_dir/my_lib.js');

ReactDOM.render(
(<BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/component_route" component={my_lib.ExampleComponent}>
        </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>)
, document.getElementById("root"));
```

So in `./library_dir/my_lib.js`, I want to be able to export MULTIPLE reactjs classes. How would I do this?

Would I want to use `export default ....` or `module.exports`? Which one and WHY? I've read that if I `import react` in this lib, I can't do a `module.exports`.

Can someone give me an example where in `./library_dir/my_lib.js`, I would be able to export multiple react classes that would look something like this?

```
import React from 'react';

my_lib = { 
        test_function: function() {
                alert("TEST FUNCTION CALLED");
        },  
        // How would I do this bellow?
        ExampleComonent: class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {
                constructor(props) {
                        super(props);
                        // doing all thing things...
                }
                render() {
                        return (
                        <h1>This is ExampleComponent.</h1>
                        );
                }
        }   
        // I need to be able to export multiple components, so here's another one.
        ExampleComonentTwo: class ExampleComponentTwo extends React.Component {
                constructor(props) {
                        super(props);
                        // doing all thing things...
                }
                render() {
                        return (
                        <h1>This is ExampleComponentTwo.</h1>
                        );
                }
        }
}

export default my_lib;
```

Comment: Have you checked this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30762734/multiple-react-components-in-a-single-module ?

Answer (score 0):

As we know `module` is a plain JavaScript object with an `exports` property. `exports` is a plain JavaScript variable that happens to be set to `module.exports`. And `export default` is syntax from ES6.

Many people consider `module.exports = ...` to be equivalent to `export default ...` and `exports.foo ...` to be equivalent to `export const foo = ...`. That's not quite true though, or at least not how Babel does it.

ES6 `default` exports are actually also *named* exports, except that `default` is a "reserved" name and there is special syntax support for it. Lets have a look how Babel compiles named and default exports:

```
// input
export const foo = 42;
export default 21;

// output
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
var foo = exports.foo = 42;
exports.default = 21;
```

Here we can see that the default export becomes a property on the `exports` object, just like `foo`.

I would like to suggest to you use one `index.js` file, where you have to export your components from lib and use them in your actual implementations.

I think following links will help you in more to resolve your problems.

1. [Why es6 react component works only with “export default”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31852933/why-es6-react-component-works-only-with-export-default)
2. [Multiple React components in a single module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30762734/multiple-react-components-in-a-single-module)

Hope this will help you !!